# Attempting to fix USB drive not detected problem, problem in console

Tags: usb, live-usb, usb-drive, usb-modem, usb-installation

I follow the instructions described on the portal, Linux Ubuntu, which talks about how to fix a non-detecting USB device when connected to a USB port.

ubuntu @ ubuntu: ~ $ sudo apt-get install -y python-dev software-properties-common wget vim

```
Reading package lists ... Done
Building a dependency tree
Reading status information ... Done
The python-dev package does not have a version available but is referenced by another package.
Typically, this means that the package is missing, has been replaced with another one
package or is not available from currently set sources.
However, the following packages replace it:
   python-dev-is-python3

E: The python-dev package is not a candidate for installation
ubuntu @ ubuntu: ~ $
```

Here is the screenshot of the terminal (originally posted as an answer)

[image]

Comment: How is a USB connection issue tied to a software installation issue? What is the link for the instructions that you refer to? What version Ubuntu?

Comment: Additional information should be [added to the question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1395997/edit) and  not posted as an answer (solution) to the question.

Comment: What's the point of posting a screenshot of the same thing you already had in text (as it should be)? And it doesn't answer the first question: *How is a USB connection issue tied to a software installation issue? What is the link for the instructions that you refer to? What version Ubuntu?* Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

python-dev has been upgraded to python3-dev in Ubuntu 20.04 and later. Open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-dev software-properties-common wget vim
```